# Lookaround Regex engine

Tags: java, regex

How does the regex engine work in terms of lookaround? my specific query is the following:

If I type `^(?!ABC)$`, will that look through an entire string for the substring ABC?

Secondly, how would I perform two operations in one regex? Say I wanted to find a string with an odd number of `b`'s and an even number of `c`'s?

EDIT: I only want to talk regarding regexes; I know this can be done in other ways.

This is what I'm using:

```
\b(?=[^A]*A([^A]*A[^A]*A)*[^A]*)([^C]*(C[^C]*C[^C]*)*[^C]*)\b
```

It fails on `CC` but should only pull out strings with odd `a`'s and `c`'s.

Comment: Your pattern `\b(?=[^A]*A([^A]*A[^A]A)[^A])([^C](C[^C]C[^C])*[^C]*)\b` is missing several stars and one \b, it must read `\b(?=[^A]*A([^A]*A[^A]*A)*[^A]\b)([^C]*(C[^C]*C[^C]*)*[^C]*)\b`

Comment: @maaartinus: A little late I know, but the asterisks were there all along.  It's just that the OP didn't apply code formatting, and SO tried to interpret them as markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can do this with a vanilla regular expression. It's just not pretty.

`^((cc|bb)*((bc|cb)(bb|cc)*(bc|cb))*)*(b|c((cc|bb)*((bc|cb)(bb|cc)*(bc|cb))*)*b((cc|bb)*((bc|cb)(bb|cc)*(bc|cb))*)*c)((cc|bb)*((bc|cb)(bb|cc)*(bc|cb))*)*$`

To understand the regular expression, draw a DFA with four states arranged in a square, linked forwards and backwards around the perimeter of the square.  The horizontal links represent consuming a B, while the vertical links represent consuming a C.  At the top left is the start state, representing having an even number of Cs and an even number of Bs.  The top right is the accept state, reached by consuming a B.  The bottom states are reached from the top states (and visa-versa) by consuming a C.  Now, we can make any number of transitions that preserve the parity of our Cs and Bs, and we'll end up back at the start state.  Then we consume a B, bringing us to our accept state.  Then from there, so long as we maintain the parities, we're good.  Two Cs maintain parity, as do two Bs. That's the `(cc|bb)*` bit.

But you can also maintain parity by going to the opposite corner (via a C and a B in either order), doing as many BB/CC as you like, then returning to the corner you were in (again, either way).  That's this bit: `((bc|cb)(bb|cc)*(bc|cb))*`

So, we have `((cc|bb)*((bc|cb)(bb|cc)*(bc|cb))*)*`, being a set of transitions that gets us back where we started (call it a noop).  You can make your odd B transition on either the top, in which case `b` will do, or the bottom, in which case you need to get down to the bottom with a `c`, do another noop, then have your `b`, then another noop, then the `c` back to the top.

I should mention that you can always take two regular expressions and generate a regular expression that matches only strings matched by both of the expressions.

Comment: Sorry, my previous version failed on cbc and my test somehow failed to detect this.

Answer (score 1):

> ^(?!ABC)$ will that look through an string for the substring ABC?

No, it alone matches the empty String only, it's *zero-width* negative lookahead. You can use it for things like `"^(?!ABC)A..$"` matching ABD, ADC, but not ABC.

> Secondly, how would I perform two operations in one regex? Say I wanted to find a string with an odd number of b's and an even number of c's?

Write the two patterns and put the first of them in a positive lookahead like `(?=pat1)pat2`

Comment: ok great thanks for advice. regarding ur example u say "...not ACD". Doesn't your example say if the string doesn't contain the substring ABC match A and any two other characters? so ACD would be possible?

Comment: I'm trying to merge the two together but it doesn't work...it seems to omit completely my lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp will match only empty strings.

Regexp is probably not the best option if you want to find the number of odd / even c's and b's.

Comment: Quoth the OP: **I only want to talk regarding regexes; I know this can be done in other ways.**  And maaartinus had already pointed out that `^(?!ABC)$` can only match an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The odd c pattern will look like: `^[^c]*c[^c]*(c[^c]*c)*[^c]*$` Not a very nice one, and if you want to add the even b pattern `^[^b]*(b[^b]*b)*[^b]*$` to it, the result will be all but completely unreadable.

Comment: The odd c pattern must read `^[^c]*c[^c]*(c[^c]*c[^c]*)*$` otherwise you accept consecutive c's only. It may be shortened as `^[^c]*c[^c]*((c[^c]){2})*$`. The same for the other pattern.

Comment: @maaartinus I tested it with non-consecutive c's and it seemed to work, but it took me 2 minutes to figure out what the difference between your regexp and mine was (they appear to be equivalent, but I may have missed something), all of which demonstrates the point of why not to use them. :)

Comment: Not all of the c's must be consecutive, "cccacc" is the smallest failure example.

Comment: @maaartinus I see now what you mean, thanks. "100 reasons for not using regexps unless necessary, number 56: hard to debug"

Comment: even pattern is wrong as it will fail on ACACACAC. I got the even pattern working if any one wants to know it's above in my edited post. I'm having trouble combining to find odd A's and even C's. my regex seems to omit my Kilauea and includes CC when clearly it shouldn't.

Comment: I wrote above "The same for the other pattern.". Something like `^[^b]*((b[^b]){2})*$` should do.

Comment: but I need to combine the two..odd c's and even b's. how do I write a regex to combine the two...